# matching regex pattern...using c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following and i have outlined which ones passed and which ones failed:

```
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\d\b.\d\s\b(Chapter)\b\s\d"); 
        var tru = regex.IsMatch("3.2 Chapter 23");//passed
        tru = regex.IsMatch("3.1 Chapter 1");//passed
        tru = regex.IsMatch("32.1 Chapter 1");//failed
        tru = regex.IsMatch("3.31 Chapter 1");//failed
        tru = regex.IsMatch("33.3 Chapter 13");//failed
        tru = regex.IsMatch("32.23 Chapter 13");//failed
```

The correct format for my string should be:

starts with a 1 to 3 digit number then a "."then a 1 to 3 digit number then a "." then one whitespace" "then the word"Chapter" then one whitespace" "then another 1 to 3 digit number

I'm using .Net 4.5

So All 6 should pass of my examples should pass. I'm close. What am I missing in my regex? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just for myself and others, can you say what version of the .NET framework you are using? (Recently ran into a version specific problem with wildcard searches myself)

Comment: i updated my question

Comment: I think you need to escape the dot in your Regex.  It should be `\.` because a dot by itself matches any character.

Comment: Your use of word boundaries (`\b`) are redundant. You can safely omit them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is the `\d` matches a single digit. Replace that with a `\d+` to match one or more digits:

```
^\d+\b.\d+\s\b(Chapter)\b\s\d+
```

Or if you want to limit it to specifically 1 to 3 digits, use `{1,3}`:

```
^\d{1,3}\b.\d{1,3}\s\b(Chapter)\b\s\d{1,3}
```

Here is how it works: https://regex101.com/r/dO7tU9/1

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description, none of your samples should pass:

> starts with a 1 to 3 digit number then a "."then a 1 to 3 digit number then a "."

your requirements are for two `.` total.  None of your samples have that.

If you want your samples to pass, with one `.`, you're looking for:

```
^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3} Chapter \d{1,3}
```

set requirements on your `\d` to be one to three digits using `{1,3}`

---

if you *do* require an extra `.`, just add another `\.` accordingly (and alter your samples to match)

Comment: two of the samples did pass...look at anderson pimentel's answer...he built off of what i had and that works perfectly

Comment: word boundaries (`\b`) aren't what you need.  I was stating that your description doesn't match your samples.

Answer (score 1):

^\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}\s(Chapter)\s\d{1,3}$

This regex states:

Any decimal digit { Exactly 1 through 3 times } . any decimal digit { Exactly 1 through 3 times } whitespace (Chapter) whitespace any decimal digit { Exactly 1 through 3 times } globally

Answer (score 1):

The following regular expression fulfils your requirements:

^\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}\sChapter\s\d{1,3}$